# How to get IP behind NAT?

Tags: nat

I have an e-shopping site. I want to sale any things in this site and users pay money from ebanking from cart and use service from one bank to do this. This bank identify my site by site ip. But when I redirect from my site to bank site, the bank says that Your ip that passed is difference than your site ip. any one can tell me what happend and how to i check this difference?

Answer (score 2):

You should re-edit your question to make clear what you are doing. For the title I suppose you are using NAT. If this is the case the local IP that you see is not the IP the bank sees. Outside of your network only the address of the router is visible.

You should use the IP of the router instead of the one on your internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Matteo said, re-edit this.  It's not clear what you're trying to do here: are you saying your bank looks at the requests from your site's IP address as part of it's authentication?  If that's true, and you're redirecting (302 moved or whatever) your site's visitors to your bank, then the bank's going to see the *visitor's* IP address, not your site's IP address.